# Importing Date and Time column data with Python

Tags: python, datetime, import

I am tying to import the a large .txt file that contains the Date and Time data it the first column. A sample of the data is shown below:

```
       Time (UTCG)                  Mean_Motion (deg/sec)

 ------------------------           ---------------------    
 16 Jul 2017 22:46:47.000                 0.063846        
 16 Jul 2017 22:47:47.000                 0.063847        
 16 Jul 2017 22:48:46.128                 0.063851
```

How can I import the Time (UTCG) column as a single DateTime column into Python?
When I try it now the spaces in the Time column are acting as delimiters and not putting the entire Date and Time data into a single column.

Comment: What library are you using for the import, and what are you specifying as the delimiter?

Comment: I'm trying it with Pandas. I tried using " " as a delimiter but as expected that doesn't work well with the spaces in the time column. I don't know how to preserve the Time column with all of its spaces while keeping the other data columns separate. I'm not very experienced with python so I don't really know the right way or library to start with.

Comment: Do you know if the data is tab-delimited, or if it's just multiple spaces? I did some tests with spaces, and it looks like you can do `pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='    ')`. Otherwise if it's tabs you can do `pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='\t')`

Answer (score 0):

To find out what the delimiter of the file is, you can read the file in and see the first line

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    print(f.readline())
```

That will show you the text and you can identify whether it's tab characters (\t) or just spaces between the columns. Use that character as the sep argument, like

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='\t')
```

or

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='    ')
```